# Order sum aggregate in output

Tags: sql, oracle

I've 2 tables, purchases and customers.
Customers has cid, cname...
Purchases has total_price of purchase, one cid has multiple purchases.
I need to find cname and maximum total price spent by top 3 customers.
I'm doing this

```
select c.cname, 
       sum(p.total_price) 
  from purchases p
       inner join 
       customers c 
         on p.cid=c.cid
 where p.total_price <= (select max(total_price) 
                           from purchases
                        ) 
group by p.cid,
         c.cname
order by c.cname;
```

I'm getting the sum total but I can't order it and get the top 3 spending customers.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have to `ORDER BY sum(p.total_price) DESC`

Comment: ...which you may or may not be able to do, based on what exactly you're using.  We in PLSQL, MSSQL, mySQL, Access, sqlite, or what?

Comment: I'm using Oracle on unix server

Comment: I can use the order by you specified and after that how can I only output the top 2 rows? can I use rownum<=2 after orderby?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but I gotta expect it supports the `SELECT TOP x` syntax, right?

Comment: It shows error for select top x, can i use rownum<=3 anywhere in the query?

Comment: @LDMJoe I thought so too when I moved from T-SQL to PL/SQL, but no.. they're different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a `ROWNUM <= 3` condition and an appropriate `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT
    cname
    , total_purchase
FROM (SELECT
          c.cname
        , sum(p.total_price) as total_purchase
      FROM customers c
          INNER JOIN purchases p on p.cid = c.cid
      GROUP BY c.cname
      ORDER BY total_purchase DESC) RS
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3;
```

In Oracle you need to order the result set before limiting it to the top 3 customers, which is why `ROWNUM <= 3` is in the outer query.

Comment: I'm using oracle, it shows error for select top x, can i use rownum<=3 anywhere in the query?

Comment: thanks man, in oracle it needs order by sum(total_price) worked after using that :) thank you

Comment: @SamKeith in Oracle, you can refer to the column alias in the order by clause (since that's applied after the specied column list is processed, meaning it knows about the alias). You may have had an issue with Radu's query since the column alias shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @Boneist Corrected, thank you for pointing it out (it was a remainder from the initial version of the query, which I wrote assuming it was T-SQL).

Comment: is there a way to get only the top most spender in this query if there are more than 1 with same amount and it should display all? maybe I can use max(sum(qty)), it gives me not a single group function error  @Boneist